# The page already appear but the article still on the same page

Tags: php

I want to limit my articles to 3 per page ... the page has appeared but the article is still on one page .

```
require_once 'koneksi.php';
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM tbl_artikel");
$aktif = 'artikel';
 $halaman = 3;
  $page = isset($_GET["halaman"]) ? (int)$_GET["halaman"] : 1;
  $mulai = ($page>1) ? ($page * $halaman) - $halaman : 0;
  $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $pages = ceil($total/$halaman);            
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_artikel LIMIT $mulai, $halaman";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($koneksi, $query);
  $no =$mulai+1;
?>
```

and here is the code for article

```
<?php while($artikel = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>
<div class="artikel">
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="post mb-2">
                            <span class="tgl"><?= date('d M y', strtotime($artikel['tanggal'])) ?></span>
                            <span class="judul"><a href="detail_artikel.php?id=<?= $artikel['id'] ?>"><?= $artikel['judul'] ?></a></span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                        <div class="clearfix" style="text-align: justify;">
                            <img src="images/artikel/<?= $artikel['foto'] ?>" alt="" width="200px" class="float-left mr-2">
                            <?= substr($artikel['isi'], 0, 150) . '...' ?>
                        </div>
```

Comment: You are looping through `$result`; don't you want `$result2`? Also, try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_artikel` if you want a count.